# Odoo custom field to kanban grouped stage column

Tags: odoo, kanban

I added a new custom field(many2many) to the model hr.recruitment.stage ,please refer to the below image for reference,
[image]

And trying to display it in the grouped kanban column view of hr.applicant, please refer to the below image for reference
[image]

Here I added the subtitle text by writing a custom addon, in the path static/src/xml/filename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="web.KanbanView.Group" t-inherit-mode="primary">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_header_title')]" position="after">
            <span>Subtitle</span>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

in the place of subtitle, I want to display the newly added many2many field values from the hr.recruitment.stage model, here I referred to kanban_column.js and I'm not able to figure out how to pass the value of the newly added field(many2many) to the javascript and display the value in the grouped kanban column view of hr.applicant. I request you to please guide me to achieve this and it will be very useful for me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add the `x_recruiters` field to the kanban fields:

```
<record id="hr_kanban_view_applicant" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.kanban.view.applicant</field>
    <field name="model">hr.applicant</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_recruitment.hr_kanban_view_applicant"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <progressbar position="before">
            <field name="x_recruiters"/>
        </progressbar>
    </field>
</record>
```

It will automatically read and add the `x_recruiters` field to the `data` object.

Then add the `recruiters` names instead of the `Subtitle` text:

```xml
<t t-if="widget.data_records.length != 0">
    <t t-foreach="widget.data_records[0].data.x_recruiters.data" t-as="stage">
        <span t-esc="stage.data.display_name"/>
        <br/>
    </t>
</t>
```

***Edit:***

You can alter the kanban column to read the recruiters from the stage model and show them after it is rendered.

```js
odoo.define('kanban_group_extended.KanbanColumn', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var KanbanColumn = require('web.KanbanColumn');

    KanbanColumn.include({
        renderElement: function () {
           this._super();
           this.set_recruiters();
        },
        set_recruiters: function() {
            var self = this;
            var kanban_header_title = self.$('.o_kanban_header_title');
            this._rpc({
                model: self.relation,
                method: 'read',
                args: [[self.id], ["x_recruiters"]],
            }).then(function (records) {
                return self._rpc({
                        model: self.data.fields["x_recruiters"].relation,
                        method: 'read',
                        args: [records[0]["x_recruiters"], ['display_name']],
                    }).then(function (values) {
                        _.each(values, function (value) {
                            kanban_header_title.after("<span>" + value['display_name'] + "</span><br/>");
                        });
                    });
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Add the js file to the assets backend:

```
<template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="Kanban Backend Assets">
    <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/kanban_group_extended/static/src/js/KanbanColumn.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kenly, It works... but this is fully based on hr.applicant model, if I add a new column, it returns empty, and when I drag a candidate to that column, then the data are displayed. , Can we make it coming from hr.recruitment.stage model? so it will display the data even the column is empty, can we do this? if so please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes of course it uses the first record in the group. It depends on the `data_records` object and yes you can get recruiters from the `stage_id` record even when there is no record in the group. Check my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kenly, this works with minor modifications thank you so much....